# How can I automate the user creation in Linux servers using Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, devops

Well I'm trying to create a script to automate the user creation in Linux servers, so I generated the ssh keys in each server and made a code like this:

```
user = teste
p = 'senha123' 
os.system("ssh myuser@lab sudo useradd -p " + p + " -d "+ "/home/" + user+ " -m "+ " -c \""+ name+"\" " + user)`
```

But, I'm getting the error:

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN useradd -D useradd -D [options]

Options: -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR base directory for the home directory of the new account -c, --comment COMMENT GECOS field of the new account -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR home directory of the new account -D, --defaults print or change default useradd configuration -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE expiration date of the new account -f, --inactive INACTIVE password inactivity period of the new account -g, --gid GROUP name or ID of the primary group of the new account -G, --groups GROUPS list of supplementary groups of the new account -h, --help display this help message and exit -k, --skel SKEL_DIR use this alternative skeleton directory -K, --key KEY=VALUE override /etc/login.defs defaults -l, --no-log-init do not add the user to the lastlog and faillog databases -m, --create-home create the user's home directory -M, --no-create-home do not create the user's home directory -N, --no-user-group do not create a group with the same name as the user -o, --non-unique allow to create users with duplicate (non-unique) UID -p, --password PASSWORD encrypted password of the new account -r, --system create a system account -R, --root CHROOT_DIR directory to chroot into -s, --shell SHELL login shell of the new account -u, --uid UID user ID of the new account -U, --user-group create a group with the same name as the user -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user ma pping

512
```

When I remove `ssh myuser@lab` part, the script work in the localhost.

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Just a comment: why are you setting out to re-invent the wheel badly when there are options like `ansible` or `saltstack`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a user in linux using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3190955/608639), [Login via ssh using publickey and create a new user using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45726460/608639), [What is the simplest way to SSH using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1233655/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `ssh` as if it used `execve(2)` semantics, where you pass commands and arguments as individual parameters (the way `sudo`, `xargs`, and `find -exec` works).

`ssh` instead uses `system(3)` semantics, so it expects a single literal shell command (like `su`, `eval`, `bash -c` and Python's `os.system`).

One general purpose way of doing this for arbitrary commands is to first assign the shell command you want to run to another string:

```
remote_command="sudo useradd -p " + p + " -d "+ "/home/" + user+ " -m "+ " -c \""+ name+"\" " + user
```

And then use `shlex.quote` to escape it for `ssh`:

```
import shlex
os.system("ssh myuser@lab " + shlex.quote(remote_command))
```

Alternatively, skip the `system()` to avoid having to add another layer of escaping:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ssh", "myuser@lab", remote_command], shell=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed answer. It worked and help me to understand a lot better the pyhton and shell behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if it will work but can you try it once:

```
os.system("ssh myuser@lab \'sudo useradd -p " + p + " -d "+ "/home/" + user+ " -m "+ " -c \""+ name+"\" " + user+"\'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but the os module gets confused when many parameters is passed to it, then it doesn't work.